# Pass optional argument from parent to child in Ruby

Tags: ruby, dry, argument-passing

There must be a DRY way to do this without two separate calls to `File.open`, and without peeking at what `File.open`'s default value for `permissions` is.  Right?

```
def ensure_file(path, contents, permissions=nil)
  if permissions.nil?
    File.open(path, 'w') do |f|
      f.puts(contents)
    end
  else
    File.open(path, 'w', permissions) do |f|
      f.puts(contents)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a splat (i.e. `*some_array`) will work in the general case:

```
def ensure_file(path, contents, permissions=nil)
  # Build you array:
  extra_args = []
  extra_args << permissions if permissions
  # Use it:
  File.open(path, 'w', *extra_args) do |f|
    f.puts(contents)
  end
end
```

In this case, you are already getting `permissions` as a parameter, so you can simplify this (and make it even more general) by allowing any number of optional arguments and passing them:

```
def ensure_file(path, contents, *extra_args)
  File.open(path, 'w', *extra_args) do |f|
    f.puts(contents)
  end
end
```

The only difference is that if too many arguments are passed, the `ArgumentError` will be raised when calling `File.open` instead of your `ensure_file`.

Comment: Beat me to it. I was thinking of `args = [path, 'w', permissions].reject(&:nil?)` and `File.open(*args)` but that's needlessly complicated, a separate `extra_args` is much nicer.

Comment: @muistooshort: :-) I thought of using `compact`, but thought the first example should be as comprehensible as possible as is it more meant for illustration that actual use.

Answer (score 1):

```
File.open(path, 'w') do |f|
  f.puts(contents)
  f.chmod(permission) if permission
end
```